# Inner Join - Error de consulta

Tags: php

Tengo una cuestión. Resulta, que deseo poder insertar la información por medio del "Inner Join", pero el problema, es que este es un campo muy nuevo para mi...

Pense haber podido solucionarlo, pero no fue así. En sí, el inner join funciona perfectamente, pero sólo me muestra la consulta de la primera columna, cuando hago un login con otra cuenta, etc, me sigue mostrando la misma consulta del primero...

````
    $userIdentification = $_POST['userIdentification'];
    $userPassword = $_POST['userPassword'];

    $dataBase = new dataBase();
    $query = $dataBase->connect()->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE userIdentification = :userIdentification AND userPassword = :userPassword');
    $query->execute(['userIdentification' => $userIdentification, 'userPassword' => $userPassword]);
    $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

    $cnx = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=academysoftware;charset=utf8mb4", "root", "");
    $informationUser = ("SELECT 'userCode', ins.institutionName, gra.gradeDescription, gro.groupDescription FROM users us INNER JOIN institutions ins ON us.institutionId = ins.institutionId INNER JOIN grades gra ON us.gradeId = gra.gradeId INNER JOIN groups gro ON us.groupId = gro.groupId ORDER BY userCode");

    $consult = $cnx->query($informationUser);
    $fila = $consult->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if ($row == true) {
        $institutionName = $fila['institutionName'];
        $gradeDescription = $fila['gradeDescription'];
        $groupDescription = $fila['groupDescription'];
        $institutionId = $row[1];
        $typeUser = $row[6];
        $userName = $row[9];
        $userLastname = $row[10];
        $userIdentification = $row[7];
        $userEmail = $row[11];
        $userNumer = $row[12];
        $userDirection = $row[13];
        $userPassword = $row[8];
        
        $_SESSION['institutionName'] = $institutionName;
        $_SESSION['gradeDescription'] = $gradeDescription;
        $_SESSION['groupDescription'] = $groupDescription;
        $_SESSION['institutionId'] = $institutionId;
        $_SESSION['typeUser'] = $typeUser;
        $_SESSION['userName'] = $userName;
        $_SESSION['userLastname'] = $userLastname;
        $_SESSION['userIdentification'] = $userIdentification;
        $_SESSION['userEmail'] = $userEmail;
        $_SESSION['userNumer'] = $userNumer;
        $_SESSION['userDirection'] = $userDirection;
        $_SESSION['userPassword'] = $userPassword;
        switch ($typeUser) {
            case 1:
                header('location:../Vista/Apps/Administrador/Index.php');
                break;

            case 2:
                header('location:../Vista/Apps/Profesor/Index.php');
                break;

            case 3:
                header('location:../Vista/Apps/Estudiante/Index.php');
                break;

            default:
                header('location:../Vista/Apps/Estudiante/Index.php');
                break;
        }
    } else {
        $errorLogin = "";
        echo $errorLogin;
    }
}```
````

Comment: Creo que te faltó el ` WHERE id = '{$row['user_id']}'` al final de la consulta (antes del ORDER BY), ya que consultas y hacer el join pero no indicas cual usuario deceas tener la información

Comment: Hola @Jonathan, gracias por tu respuesta.
Usando $informationUser = ("SELECT us.userCode, ins.institutionName, gra.gradeDescription, gro.groupDescription FROM users us INNER JOIN institutions ins ON us.institutionId = ins.institutionId INNER JOIN grades gra ON us.gradeId = gra.gradeId INNER JOIN groups gro ON us.groupId = gro.groupId WHERE us.userIdentification = '{$_SESSION['userIdentification']}'"); me sigue sin mostrar la información

Comment: Muchisimas gracias! Ya lo solucione.

Comment: Si lograste resolver, por favor, escribe un comentario como solucionaste y marca la pregunta como resuelta. Espero haber ayudado! Saludos.

Comment: En la consulta de $sql tuve que agregar el WHERE dónde podría identificar a que usuario le haré dicha consulta cómo lo comento @Jonathan anteriormente.